# Regular Expression to remove special characters from Date format

Tags: regex, special-characters

I have a date in the following format as input.

```
2002-03-20T10:21:39.334Z
```

How can I write a regular expression (without any function like replaceall etc.) To remove all the special characters`(-,:,.)` and alphabets (`T` and `Z)` from the date field?

Comment: use "2002-03-20T10:21:39.334Z".match(/\d+/g).

Comment: @HarpreetSingh I don't need to use any function like match also. Need a simple regex to match only the integers

Comment: RegEx is inside the parenthesis of match function. And how will you use RegEx if you don't want to use any function?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a function some place.  Remove everything that is not an integer:

```js
str = '2002-03-20T10:21:39.334Z';
str = str.replace(/\D/g, '');
console.log(str); //returns '20020320102139334'
```